# Upload file to S3 bucket using curl

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file (plaintext) to my S3 bucket. I'm using the PUT request and have a lambda + REST api set up.

I came across this script, but can't get it to work.

```sh
file=$HOME/Documents/test.txt
bucket=my-s3bucket
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="text/plaintext"
dateValue=`date -R`
stringToSign="PUT\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key=secretkey
s3Secret=mys3secret
signature=`echo -en ${stringToSign} | openssl sha256 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -X PUT -T "${file}" \
    -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
    -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 ${s3Key}:${signature}" \
    https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: I got the following error: 
`Missing required header for this request: x-amz-content-sha256`